# Removing Table if no information is found

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table

I have a dynamic table that is created when records are being pulled. The issue that I am trying to solve for is when there are no records found. I want to delete the dynamic table. How do I do this in an if statement? Here is the code where I am trying to implement that.

```
this.exclusions.forEach(ex => this.displyedData.push(exclusionRowData(ex)));
if(this.displyedData == null)
delete(this.DisplayedColumns)
```

I feel that I am doing something wrong here.Any ideas?

Comment: Display data is never null because you initialized it as empty array. You would need to check if the array has any items via `.length > 0`

Comment: Please don't put an image of code, put code instead or create any working example which produces the issue and provide the link here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.exclusion.length !== 0 && (sample content) }
```